# How to use CSS for mobile in the right way?

Tags: android, mobile, css, responsive-design

What is the right way to define responsive design for mobile devices.
let's assume that I want to make a general design for iPhone 4 (960*640) & for the common android (800 * 480).

Should I use media queries?

```
@media (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 640px) //For iPhone landscape
@media (max-width: 640px) //For iPhone portrait
```

and should I take to consideration that the general android devices work on 800px (in landscape mode) and not 960px?

Since this is all new to me - **the question is how to define CSS in the right way? What is the right paradigma?**

Should I define it per a specific size (when I have 2 main CSS for above 960px & for bleow 960px) - or Should I define it per device (iphone or android)

Comment: Might I suggest http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A List Apart has a good [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet) on this.

Scroll down to where it says:

> These aren’t the style sheets you’re looking for